# Passing data from a view pager to a different activity

Tags: android

I have a view pager application working properly. The view pager contains different strings of data in an array displayed one at a time after a swipe. I have a button which when clicked should get the current content and pass it to another activity here is my code:

```
/*MainActivity*/
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from viewpager_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);


        item = new String[] { "Apple", "Movie", "Melon", "pawpaw",
                "Jungle", "Forest" };



        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, item);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContentActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("Currentitem", item[0].toString());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });


    }
```

Below is the ViewPagerAdapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] item;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] item) {
        this.context = context;
        this.quote = item;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        TextView item;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_pager_adapter, container,
                false);


        txtitem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quote);


        txtitem.setText(quote[position]);




        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `item[0].toString()` will always pass the first item from the array ("Apple" in this case).

Comment: so far that's what i have, i need a code that will pass the item that is in the current view of the screen not only "Apple"

Comment: so what you are able to get in the next activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine :

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
            
            int currentItem =viewPager.getCurrentItem();
              
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContentActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Currentitem", item[currentItem].toString());

            startActivity(i);
     }
  });
```